# Why does a member function needs '&' (e.g. in std::bind)?

Tags: c++, c++11

When I was playing with `std::bind` from the *C++11*-standard I recognized the following would be allowed by the compiler:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void F();
  int G(int, int);
};

void Foo::F()
{
  auto f = bind(&Foo::G, this, _1, _2);
  cout << f(1,2) << endl;
}

int Foo::G(int a, int b)
{
  cout << a << ',' << b << endl;
  return 666;
}
```

But if I eliminated the '&' in front of the `Foo::G` in the `bind`-line, I would get some compiler errors (using MinGW 4.7).

Why is `Foo::G` not valid as a pointer to a member function, although `H` and `&H` would both work for "usual" functions?

LG ntor

Comment: No particular reason -- Bjarne just decided to require the `&` to take the address of a member function.

Comment: ... Or said otherwise, the name of a member function does not decay to a pointer-to-member function as a function decays to pointer-to-function.

Comment: And if C++ didn't have to be backwards compatible with C, I guarantee you that functions wouldn't decay to pointers either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

& is required to take address of a member function, some compilers will allow you to omit the same but it is non-standard and at times confusing.

you can read about member function pointers in here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

Answer (score 2):

I take it that one of the reasons could have been consistency. Recall that within a class, you can say

```
MyClassOrOneOfItsBases::memberFunction();
```

It compiles fine, since the qualified name names the member function, instead of forming a pointer to member.

Comment: Even more vivid with member data: `void MyClass::foo(){ bar(MyClass::baz); }`.

Comment: It was only ment with member-function pointers, but thx anyway.

Comment: I think this is the right reason.  It doesn't matter, in context, whether you name a free function or its pointer, since the function-call operator works with either.  But for pmf it changes everything.  BTW data is not at all a parallel case, since non-member data also needs `&` to form a pointer.